# RESTful error response Spring instead of tomcat page

Tags: java, json, spring, tomcat, spring-restcontroller

I want to return a custom JSON as response body in case of errors. I tried doing this for 404 error code. I created a controller which looks like this.

```
@RequestMapping("/**")
@Controller
public class IOTExceptionController {

   public void handleInvalidURL() throws ResourceNotFoundException {
       throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Requested resource does not exist."
            + " Please check the URL.");
   }
}
```

And the ControllerAdvice class I've setup will return the response as JSON.

So whatever URL which will not be found in other controllers will be handled here and 404 error is returned. 
Unfortunately, the Tomcat error page for 404 is all I'm getting. Can anyone please let me know whether there is any flaw in this logic/code?

Comment: try @RequestMapping("/")

Comment: Tried that with no luck.

Comment: Put your @RequestMapping("/**") to your method, instead of controller

Comment: @TharsanSivakumar It worked. But now, there is no distinction between 405 and 404. HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException is not thrown and it will come to this controller even when the Controller with same path (but different method) exists. So I have to find another way to accomplish this task. Thank you for your help